# I'm having a problem with assigned value in declaring functions in Pine

Tags: function, pine-script

So, I built an indicator which used to work until this month and I can't find no way to fix it:

```
rising_(values, length) =>
    current_ = values[0]
    ok_ = false
    if length>0 and length<bar_index
        ok_ := true
        for i = 1 to length
            if ( not na(values[i]) and current_ <= values[i] )
                ok_ := false
                break
    ok_
```

This function used to return true or false thoroughly (and it does if applied to other indicators); when I run it on my indicator it returns an error:

> Cannot call 'operator >' with arguments (series[bool], literal integer); available overloads: >(float, float) => bool; >(input float, input float) => input bool; >(const float, const float) => const bool; >(float, series[float]) => series[bool]; >(series[float], float) => series[bool]; >(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool];

> Cannot call 'operator <' with arguments (series[bool], series[integer]); available overloads: <(float, float) => bool; <(input float, input float) => input bool; <(const float, const float) => const bool; <(float, series[float]) => series[bool]; <(series[float], float) => series[bool]; <(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool];

> "for" loop`s index cannot use a string value.

Any clues are well accepted.

Comment: You specified invalid arguments for the function `rising_()`.

Comment: Is it because I'm using barssince output as a length? Every time I call `rising(src, barssince(event))` and it does work on other indicators but mine

Comment: There can be many reasons, only a full script can establish the true cause. I assume that the function `rising_()` is called several times with different arguments.

Comment: If i shared with you the whole script would you look for the reason? I only used it like this:

line 10 `rising(values, length) =>`

line 318 `rising_(high, barssince(istop==high)`

line 323 `rising_(rsi, barssince(isbot==low)`

Comment: Please present a [Minimal, Verifiables, Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can help you with.